# mostrar datos en la cabecera de una tabla

Tags: php, html5, pdo

quisiera mostrar datos en la cabecera de una tabla, pero no consigo que se me muestre como quiero; ya que este campo a mostrar en la cabecera es llamado desde la bd  anexo una imagen de como se deben mostrar los datos y  mi código fuente.

la linea a mostrar en la cabecera seria `{$linea['hora_sorteo']}` que es la que esta marcada en rojo en la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 <?php
    $sql2 = "SELECT 
    animalitos.id,
    animalitos.portada,
    animalitos.nombre,
    animalitos.numero,
    animalitos.color,
    animalitos.grupo,
    animalitos.numero_letras,
    resultado.id,
    resultado.fk_animalitos,
    resultado.fk_hora_sorteo,
    resultado.fecha,
    hora_sorteo.id,
    hora_sorteo.hora_sorteo
           FROM animalitos 
                INNER JOIN resultado ON animalitos.id=resultado.fk_animalitos  
                INNER JOIN hora_sorteo ON resultado.fk_hora_sorteo=hora_sorteo.id
                WHERE resultado.fecha BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE()-7 AND CURRENT_DATE()-1 ORDER BY resultado.id, resultado.fk_hora_sorteo  DESC ";

       $consulta = $DB_con->prepare($sql2);
       $consulta->execute();
       if($consulta->rowCount() > 0){
       $i=1;


    while ($linea = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    echo "<table  class='striped responsive-table centered'>";
    echo "<thead>
    <tr>
    <th data-field='Operaciones'>{$linea['hora_sorteo']}</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>";

    echo "<tr>
    <td align=center>{$linea['numero']} - {$linea['nombre']}</td>
         </tr>";

       $i++;
      }
    }

   else

   echo "<div class='col s12 card-panel yellow darken-2 center'>
   <h5 class='black-text text-darken-2 center CONDENSED LIGHT5'>
   ¡ Advertencia: No se ha encontrado ningún registro !
   </h5>
   </div>";
   echo "</table>";
   ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo pude resolver anexo codigo:

```
<?php
$consulta = $DB_con->query("SELECT * FROM hora_sorteo");
for ($set = array (); $row = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); $set[] = $row);
?>
<table  class='striped responsive-table centered'>
<thead>
<tr>
<?php for($i=0;$i<count($set);$i++){
echo "<th>" . $set[$i]['hora_sorteo'] . "</th>"; 
}?>
</tr>
</thead>
```